# How to get to the settings panel in 22.10

Tags: menu, system-settings, 22.10

To put the question into context, I updated from 20.04 to 22.10 and the gear icon area looks like this:

[image]

I don't know if this is the way it should be (Also do not know why it things I have a laptop because of the Performance option there, when it is a desktop), but I am trying to get to the settings icon. I can not find it here. I even tried clicking on the sound option and then on the Sound Setting at the bottom but it does not do anything, nothing opens or happens.

[image]

Currently I am a bit lost to how to get to the settings, even a terminal command option to get to the settings would  help, but I also wanted to know if this is how this menu is supposed to look like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone comes here with the same issue, for some reason, updating from 22.04 to 22.10 ended up removing several gnome packages, including the `gnome-control-center` which was the specific one missing here.

I ended up installing many gnome packages with the 43 version, but this specific one was the one missing after the upgrade. So to restore the functionality run this from a terminal:

```
sudo apt install gnome-control-center
```